# Can world no. 1 in tennis play qualifying?

Tags: tennis, ranking, qualifying

So apparently, [Elena Rybakina who is world no. 10 would have to play qualifying at a recent WTA event if she wouldn't withdraw](https://tennis-infinity.com/wta/why-world-no-10-rybakina-will-need-to-play-qualifying-at-wta-500-event).

I was wondering if it's possible that it would somehow happen that world number one will have to play the qualifying in ATP or WTA.

Answer (score 1):

If the player was ranked No. 1 when the draw is decided, then it would not happen.

This is a quite rare case that Rybakina, who is currently ranked No 10, should have to play in qualifying, though she finally withdrew.

When the draw was decided, Rybakina was ranked No 25, and only 12 players were invited directly into the main draw. So she should have played qualifying. But she did very well in the Australia Open which is later than the Qatar Total open draw, she rose up to No 10.